# Upgrading Gnome Shell Extensions

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, and all the gnome shell extensions listed by the Gnome Tweak tool are disabled. What's the easiest way to fix/upgrade them? Do I need to manually delete, re-download and install them?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) with Firefox or Epiphany, then to "Installed extensions". Some may me grayed out, that means that they aren't available in Gnome 3.4, but others probably have a green icon on the left with which you can update the extension.

Comment: Is there some other way? The site extensions.gnome.org is incredibly buggy. I have a dozen extensions installed, but every page on that site is blank...

Comment: There is no other way yet. But it probably doesn't work if you installed them in /usr/share/... Try reinstalling them through the website and make sure you have scripts activated.

Comment: It's a buggy site. I get a JS error for the code: `$.ajaxSettings.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = $.cookie('csrftoken');` main.js line 13.

Comment: For me, it works just fine. Try epiphany ("Web Browser") if you used FF before.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a [webupd8 extension](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/gnome-shell-extension-updater.html) for updating all extensions.

Note, the install instructions in the article are wrong, and should actually be:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnome-common
git clone git://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-updater.git
cd gnome-shell-extension-updater
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```